# MySQL Km Calculation

Tags: mysql

The sample table is as follows. The column Km shows the car's km counter value. It is a constantly increasing value. I automatically record this data every 5 minutes in a km column.

```html
ID TIMESTAMP             KM
1     3.11.2017 10:00     3778733
2     3.11.2017 10:05     3778774
3     3.11.2017 10:10     3778816
4     3.11.2017 10:15     3778857
5     3.11.2017 10:20     3778897
6     3.11.2017 10:25     3778937
7     3.11.2017 10:30     3778976
8     3.11.2017 10:35     3779015
9     3.11.2017 10:40     3779054
10   3.11.2017 10:45     3779094
11   3.11.2017 10:50     3779138
12   3.11.2017 10:55     3779178
13   3.11.2017 11:00     3779217
14   3.11.2017 11:05     3779260
15   3.11.2017 11:10     3779302
16   3.11.2017 11:15     3779343
17   3.11.2017 11:20     3779384
18   3.11.2017 11:25     3779426
19   3.11.2017 11:30     3779468
20   3.11.2017 11:35     3779511
21   3.11.2017 11:40     3779558
22   3.11.2017 11:45     3779600
23   3.11.2017 11:50     3779641
24   3.11.2017 11:55     3779681
25   3.11.2017 12:00     3779723
26   3.11.2017 12:05     3779764
27   3.11.2017 12:10     3779807
28   3.11.2017 12:15     3779849
29   3.11.2017 12:20     3779890
30   3.11.2017 12:25     3779932
31   3.11.2017 12:30     3779981
32   3.11.2017 12:35     3780024
33   3.11.2017 12:40     3780066
34   3.11.2017 12:45     3780110
35   3.11.2017 12:50     3780152
36   3.11.2017 12:55     3780195
37   3.11.2017 13:00     3780200
```

I want to calculate the distance the car travels every hour (with a view table).

Example Output Table;

```
....
.....
......
10:00 - 11:00 => 484
11:00 - 12:00 => 506
12:00 - 13:00 => 477
......
.....
....
```

How do I write sql code? can you help me?

Comment: group by date and hour subtracting min(km) from max(km)

Comment: Then I get the difference between 0 and 55 minutes in the same hour. Every hour is lost for 5 minutes.

Comment: In that case create a union to generate some dummy entries for the 0 minute values See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dummy records for the 0 minute rows using a union before grouping. Note this will only work if you don't go across day boundaries - if you do then write a procedure to do this.

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t
(ID int,    tv varchar(20), ts datetime  ,  dt date, hr int,         KM int);
insert into t (id,tv,km) values
(1    ,  '3.11.2017 10:00'    ,  3778733),
(2    ,  '3.11.2017 10:05'    ,  3778774),
(3    ,  '3.11.2017 10:10'    ,  3778816),
(4    ,  '3.11.2017 10:15'    ,  3778857),
(5    ,  '3.11.2017 10:20'    ,  3778897),
(6    ,  '3.11.2017 10:25'    ,  3778937),
(7    ,  '3.11.2017 10:30'    ,  3778976),
(8    ,  '3.11.2017 10:35'    ,  3779015),
(9    ,  '3.11.2017 10:40'    ,  3779054),
(10,      '3.11.2017 10:45'   ,  3779094),
(11,      '3.11.2017 10:50'   ,  3779138),
(12,      '3.11.2017 10:55'   ,  3779178),
(13 , '3.11.2017 11:00',        3779217),
(14 ,  '3.11.2017 11:05',       3779260),
(15 ,  '3.11.2017 11:10',       3779302),
(16 ,  '3.11.2017 11:15',       3779343),
(17 ,  '3.11.2017 11:20',       3779384),
(18 ,  '3.11.2017 11:25',       3779426),
(19 ,  '3.11.2017 11:30',       3779468),
(20 ,  '3.11.2017 11:35',       3779511),
(21 ,  '3.11.2017 11:40',       3779558),
(22 ,  '3.11.2017 11:45',       3779600),
(23 ,  '3.11.2017 11:50',       3779641),
(24 ,  '3.11.2017 11:55',       3779681),
(25 ,  '3.11.2017 12:00',       3779723),
(26 ,  '3.11.2017 12:05',       3779764),
(27 ,  '3.11.2017 12:10',       3779807),
(28 ,  '3.11.2017 12:15',       3779849),
(29  , '3.11.2017 12:20',       3779890),
(30 ,  '3.11.2017 12:25',       3779932),
(31 ,  '3.11.2017 12:30',       3779981),
(32 ,  '3.11.2017 12:35',       3780024),
(33 ,  '3.11.2017 12:40',       3780066),
(34 ,  '3.11.2017 12:45',       3780110),
(35 ,  '3.11.2017 12:50',       3780152),
(36 ,  '3.11.2017 12:55',       3780195),
(37 ,  '3.11.2017 13:00',    3780200);

select id,str_to_date(tv,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') from t;

update t 
    set ts = str_to_date(tv,'%d.%m.%Y %H:%i');
update t 
    set dt = date(ts), hr = hour(ts);

select dt,hr, min(km), max(km) ,max(km) - min(km)
from (select dt,hr,km from t
union all
select dt,hr - 1 ,km from t where minute(ts) = 0) s
group by dt,hr
```

Answer (score 0):

This query assumes you have readings exactly every 5 mins and an ID that acts like a row number. The query can be tweaked to depend only on timestamp too.

The first inner query assigns the same group number `grp` to every 12 rows (i.e. so timestamps 10.00 to 10.55, 11.00 to 11.55 and so on would have same `grp`).

The second inner query selects every 13th entry and gives it the same group number as the 12th entry, so that the 13th entry is ultimately included in two consecutive groups i.e. ID=13 (timestamp 11:00) would be in groups 0 and 1, ID=25 (timestamp 12:00) would be in groups 1 and 2 etc.

Once we have the correct grouping, the outside query is a simple select with group by on the group number, and the start and end timestamps of that group. I added a `having` clause to avoid a scenario like a single reading in an hour (i.e. distance would be 0 for that hour)

```
SELECT MIN(ts) AS start_ts, MAX(ts) AS end_ts, MAX(km) - MIN(km) distance
FROM
    (SELECT FLOOR(id / 12.001) AS grp, id, ts, km
    FROM tbl 
    UNION 
    SELECT FLOOR(id / 12) - 1 AS grp, id, ts, km
    FROM tbl
    WHERE MOD(id, 12) = 1) temp
GROUP BY grp
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY grp;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ba27b/2/0)